# Get docker PID namespace value inside code

Tags: docker, rust, process, namespaces

I have a Rust application, I have dockerized it and I run it using
`docker run ...`

Now, is there any way I can know inside the code if `docker run` is running with `--pid host`

because based on that I want to identify if code is running in Host namespace / Container namespace !
(Any solution, other than getting PID value is also welcome)

Comment: Why do you need to know this?  If you're trying to, say, kill(2) other processes, it might be more straightforward to look and see if they're there, and if the target process isn't present and you can determine you're inside a container, infer that you haven't enabled `--pid=host` (which is a pretty unusual setting IME).

Comment: @DavidMaze, actually the rust project is listing all the processes running in my system, if I use --pid host it will show my local machin's processes, otherwise it will show me containers. inside the code I want to set a flag accodingly

Comment: Right; in a container context I'd probably expect your Rust process to be the _only_ process, and the default container setup it won't be able to see host processes at all.  What are you trying to do with these other processes, and is it actually appropriate to isolate your application in a container?

Comment: @DavidMaze My rust application is distributable as an APT package & as a docker image, (here I am concerned only about the docker image). Playing with pid:host allows me to get both process data & container data. Now, I am sending this data to another application, and that application will use different storage based on that flag (process / container)

Comment: Therefore, I need this flag value inside my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read PPID environment variable. If is greater than 0, is --pid=host

With out host

```
docker run --rm -ti alpine /bin/sh
/ # set
BB_ASH_VERSION='1.35.0'
FUNCNAME=''
HISTFILE='/root/.ash_history'
HOME='/root'
HOSTNAME='6969b06aca68'
IFS='
'
LINENO=''
OPTIND='1'
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

   PPID='0'

PS1='\w \$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/'
SHLVL='1'
TERM='xterm'
/ #
```

With host

```
docker run --pid=host --rm -ti alpine /bin/sh
 # set
B_ASH_VERSION='1.35.0'
UNCNAME=''
ISTFILE='/root/.ash_history'
OME='/root'
OSTNAME='93bad7055e04'
FS='

INENO=''
PTIND='1'
ATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

   PID='1475'

S1='\w \$ '
S2='> '
S4='+ '
WD='/'
HLVL='1'
ERM='xterm'
 #
```

Comment: I'd expect this to be equivalent to checking if the process ID is 1.  This approach won't necessarily work if the main container process is being launched from a shell script or if you explicitly have an init system in the container. (Process 1 has some special responsibilities and it's not uncommon to run a tiny init like `tini` as process 1, in which case the pid will not be 1 and the ppid will be 1, not 0.)

Comment: Hello, yes I know is not the complete solution. But the only way to interact outside the container is the environnement variable. Other information, is `ps` shell command. When you use --pid=host you see all process and so what the PPID it is. You can try to work this two informations